# Repeating alarm at 10:30am and repeat every hour and it should get canceled at 3:30pm. The whole process should repeat everyday

Tags: android, alarmmanager

This is the code that I've been trying with....

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar now=Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

//Create a new Pending Intent and add it to the Alarm Manager

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Get_Location.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent= 
PendingIntent.getService(Main_Activity.this,0,intent,0);
if(cal.before(now))
{
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 60*60*1000,     
pendingIntent);
```

//cancellation alarm

```
Intent cancellationIntent = new Intent(this,           
CancelAlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
cancellationIntent.putExtra("key", pendingIntent);
PendingIntent cancellationPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,   
0, cancellationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal2.getTimeInMillis(),    
24*60*60*1000, cancellationPendingIntent);
```

//where cancel alarm broadcast receiver class is to cancel the alarm

By this process what I am achieving is that the alarm starts at 10:30 am and repeats every hour till 3:30 pm and gets cancelled at 3:30 pm. But how do I repeat this process daily (as the alarm is getting cancelled at 3:30 pm will it repeat the next day).

Answer (score 0):

Create a new alarm that will issue at 10:30 the next day right after you cancel your existing alarm at 3:30.  Use the `triggerAtMillis` argument to set the time you want this alarm to go off.

`setRepeating(int type, long triggerAtMillis, long intervalMillis, PendingIntent operation)`